# Typescript Parameters<> Utility for polymorphic parameter class method?

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing some customized [AudioNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode)

There are two types of `AudioNode`'s `connect` type

```
connect(destinationNode: AudioNode, output?: number, input?: number): AudioNode;
connect(destinationParam: AudioParam, output?: number): void;
```

The question is that how can I infer the type when I use `Parameters` utility in Typescript? The real code is like this.

```
_outputConnect(params: Parameters<AudioNode["connect"]>) {
  return this._outputNode.connect(...params);
}
```

I want type to be the first parameter that is

`connect(destinationNode: AudioNode, output?: number, input?: number): AudioNode;`

But actually, it is the second one.

`connect(destinationParam: AudioParam, output?: number): void;`

Is there any way to type params of `connect` method with only using `Parameter` utility in this case?

Comment: Terminology note: what you're calling a "polymorphic" method is more conventionally referred to as an ["overloaded"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) method.  TypeScript has difficulty with inference and overloaded functions; see the linked q/a for more information.